# Wireless network list doesn't show up on WinXP SP3

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

I have this problem since SP2. Sometimes my wireless notifier will show 'no wireless found in range' even if it's actually connected to one of them (I can surf on internet and there is no LAN connection). This is annoying, since when I want to connect to a non-default wireless connection there is no way. And if I click the 'change the order of preferred network, there is no entry under the 'preferred networks' tab. Even if I manually add one, the next time I open it, it won't show up either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried updating the driver for your wireless card?